# .NET Framework Windows Vista & 7 Features

Tags: .net, windows-vista

Where can I find the list of what .NET adds to Vista/7 like Jump list and custom window style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Officially provided by Microsoft.

Comment: This doesn't include things in the core framework like the cryptography classes that are Vista+ only, etc.