# How to draw button in title bar like in Google Chrome?

Tags: windows, delphi, vcl

I tried several components from 2000-2001, but none of them works for win7. How do I do it?

Comment: You need to master the contents of http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/controls-and-glass/ and http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2011/01/30/custom-title-bars-reprise/ and http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/...

Comment: This is exceedingly hard to do well. You need to extend the client area into the glass. Personally I would download the source of Chromium or Firefox and try to learn from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to make use of glass frame in Windows 7 using Delphi, you can follow [this tutorial](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/). There is also an [update](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2011/01/30/custom-title-bars-reprise/) available dedicated to a 64 bit bug. You can also look at some [examples](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Author/20220) by Chris Rolliston available on embarcadero developer network.

Comment: Former links are also by the same author.

Answer (score 0):

Or they probably just draw their own components like a video game would do and they emulated the windows 7 look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [rkSmartTabs](http://rmklever.com/zipfiles/rkSmartTabs1.7.zip):

[image: rkSmartTabs]

Or [IceTabSet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/icetabset/):
[image: IceTabSet]

Finally, check out the answers to these StackOverflow questions:

[Google Chrome Tabs Style UI in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924720/google-chrome-tabs-style-ui-in-delphi)

[Resources for Windows Aero Glass and Compositing dwm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822609/resources-for-windows-aero-glass-and-compositing-dwm)

Comment: Didn't you forget the "in title bar" part of the question?

Comment: I read between the lines, and figured that with these components + `borderstyle=bsNone`, the OP is closer to what he tries to achieve than with a general explanation on how to draw on a title bar.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my TChromeTabs component (http://code.google.com/p/delphi-chrome-tabs/downloads/list). As well as the Chrome Tabs implementation it includes a TForm descendant that will show you how to draw in an Aero title bar.

Answer (score -3):

[.NET Framework Windows Vista & 7 Features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893586/net-framework-windows-vista-7-features)
This maybe