# Insert button into window title bar

Tags: delphi, window

I want to insert a button inside window title bar just like TeamViewer does.

[image: teamviewer button]

Any ideeas how can i do this in delphi and make it run on all windows systems ?

Any starting point will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not at all easy if you want to support aero

Comment: when team viewer inserts the button if aero is enabled is displayed just like in the picture so i guess it doesn't support aero ... i am looking into a method not a perfect one but just an ideea on how i can achieve this

Comment: you need to handle WM_NCPAINT to replicate that behaviour

Comment: so i need to inject a module into the process address space

Comment: You want to do this in other processes?

Comment: Chris Rolliston wrote an article about this, too much for me to write an answer of the subject. See [setting-up-a-custom-titlebar](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/).

Comment: And he also wrote a follow up article, correcting some flaws. [setting-up-a-custom-title-bar-reprise](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/22/setting-up-a-custom-title-bar-reprise/)

Comment: And here is a duplicate in SO, [how-to-draw-button-in-title-bar-like-in-google-chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985929/how-to-draw-button-in-title-bar-like-in-google-chrome)

Comment: Have you looked at some skinning components, I think some of them might allow extra title buttons.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan of course i want to do it to all visible windows just like teamviewer does it

Answer (score 2):

Please refer

http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/

I think it will help you very much